# Big Query - Repeated records into separate columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've been trying this for so long now. I have a table with user details and their manager details in repeated records. What I need is to query a particular user's records along with the people who report to him. 
Data Eg:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "designation": "team member",
    "designationLevel": "3",
    "reportsTo": [
      {
        "name": "bcd",
        "designation": "team lead",
        "designationLevel": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "qwe",
        "designation": "manager",
        "designationLevel": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bcd",
    "designation": "team lead",
    "designationLevel": "2",
    "reportsTo": [
      {
        "name": "qwe",
        "designation": "manager",
        "designationLevel": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "designation": "team lead",
    "designationLevel": "2",
    "reportsTo": [
      {
        "name": "qwe",
        "designation": "manager",
        "designationLevel": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "pqr",
    "designation": "team member",
    "designationLevel": "3",
    "reportsTo": [
      {
        "name": "qwe",
        "designation": "manager",
        "designationLevel": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "xyz",
        "designation": "team lead",
        "designationLevel": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've been trying to query using is using a left join and a where clause with designationLevel and reportsTo.name

Query to fetch ppl who report to the manager "qwe"

```
SELECT manager.data as manager,teamlead.data as teamlead, teammember.data as teammember
from
(
SELECT "manager" as manager, "teamlead" as teamlead, "teammember" as teammember
) AS data
left join
(
SELECT "manager" as tag, 
concat(IFNULL(id,''),'~',IFNULL(name,''),'~',IFNULL(designation,'')) as data
FROM [some_table]
where reportsTo.name = "qwe" and designationLabel=='manager' 
group by tag, data
) as manager on manager.tag=data.manager
left join
(
SELECT "teamlead" as tag, 
concat(IFNULL(id,''),'~',IFNULL(name,''),'~',IFNULL(designation,'')) as data
FROM [some_table]
where reportsTo.name = "qwe" and designationLabel=='teamlead' 
group by tag,data
) as teamlead on teamlead.tag=data.teamlead
left join
(
SELECT "teammember" as tag, 
concat(IFNULL(id,''),'~',IFNULL(name,''),'~',IFNULL(designation,'')) as data
FROM [some_table]
where reportsTo.name = "qwe" and designationLabel=='teammember' 
group by tag,data
) as teammember on teammember.tag=data.teammember
```

This gives me a cross join of all the users. Ideally as per the data I should get

**Edited the output:**

```
manager | teamlead | teammember
qwe     | bcd      | abc 
qwe     | xyz      | pqr
```

But I feel there will be a optimum way in which this can be done? Please suggest.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Have edited the question with data and desired results

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT t.name, t.designation FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST(reportsTo) r WHERE r.name = 'qwe'
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(line) 
FROM (
  SELECT name AS manager, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() line FROM temp WHERE designation = 'manager'
) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT name AS teamlead, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() line FROM temp WHERE designation = 'teamlead'
) USING(line) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT name AS teammember, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() line FROM temp WHERE designation = 'teammember'
) USING(line)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row manager teamlead    teammember   
1   null    bcd         abc  
2   null    xyz         null
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please help me understand this? Also, I mis-typed the output result I wanted. I have edited it. Basically it needs to be a flat list with all the designations.. Can you please check that too?

Comment: Your initial output example was more-less in sync with the query you shown - so I thought I've got logic you have in mind. After you edited expected output - this is not a case anymore!

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.. Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: meantime, if you still want me to explain how my query works - first of all - it is mostly based on query you shown in the question; It gathers all managers, teamleads and teammember s reported to `'qwe'` each in separate subquery and then joins them together in one flat output using FULL OUTER JOIN on row number, So essentially, first column has all managers reported to `qwe`, second column has all teamleaders reported to `qwe` and finally - third column has all teammembers reported to `qwe` - that is based on how your initial (before you did edit) output looked !

Comment: Wow.. Thanks.. A very clean and efficient way.. My query was taking much longer for a larger dataset. Can you please please help me get the edited output?

Comment: i am not sure what exactly the logic behind that output. for example what if teamlead bcd has more than just one teammember reported to him/her. what would eb expected output in this case?

Comment: So, if there is another team member reporting to bcd,then there would be another row added with same manager and team lead details. Only the team member column would change